# Content Query Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, content-query-web-part

I am using content query web part to display pages from pages library.
I want to configure my web part to display pages according to number of page views. most popular page (according to number of views) should be on top. Is it out of the box functionality in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No, this is not included out of the box.

To achieve this, you need to add the number of page views to the page item, then sort by this number by using the Content By Query Web Part. This is not a out-of-the-box solution.

You can show the most popular pages using the rating system, but this is different than basing it on the number of views.